# Getting information back to the main thread from the called thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters

I have a "string" and a "StreamReader" in the main thread. I want to pass these to a thread which will read the streamreader into the string. I want that string to be changed in the main thread. My question is how do I do this?

Additional info: I have specific reasons as to why I want to thread this so please just stick to the specs. Also, I cannot use TPL because I cannot get framework 4.0... Again for specific reasons.

Answer (score 7):

So you make a class with a `string` and a `StreamReader` property. You pass in an instance of that class to your other thread using `ParameterizedThreadStart`. You have that other thread fill that buttercup up by writing to the `string` property on that instance of your class.

When the thread is done, your `string` property on the instance of your class will be filled up. Yay.

So something like

```
 class Foo {
     public string Bar { get; set; }
 }
```

Then:

```
 Foo foo = new Foo();
 var thread = new Thread(o => { Foo f = (Foo)o; f.Bar = "FillMeUpButterCup"; });
 thread.Start(foo);
 thread.Join();
 Console.WriteLine(foo);
```

Wow!

I left off the `StreamReader` but now you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the thread you have `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate and a parameter that you could pass there. Just create a class with two properties - `string` and `StreamReader` (and possibly whatever else you want to pass there) and pass instance of the class into thread starting method.

```
public class ThreadStartParam
{
    public string Str { get; set; }
    public StreamReader StreamReader { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Thread(YourMethod);

        var param = new ThreadStartParam();
        param.Str = "abc";
        param.StreamReader = new StreamReader();

        t.Start(param);
    }

    static void YourMethod(object param)
    {
        var p = (ThreadStartParam) param;
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about this sometime last year and I think it'll cover how to properly communicate to a thread and back from a thread. Basically create an object to pass to and from the thread and you can pass to the thread using a ParameterizedThreadStart and you can pass back by having a delegate to invoke.

http://coreyogburn.com/post/Threads-Doing-Them-Right-wGUI.aspx

More specifically in your example of the main thread realizing the changed String that you pass to the thread, I would recommend that on thread completion, you call a method that passes the string value back and re-sets the original string's value. This will prevent the thread from adding to the string while the main thread might try to read it.